# Can I use the Devel Generate module?

Tags: commerce

I have content type with the *Product ID*, *Name*, *Image*, *Description*, *Category*, and *Price* fields.

Will the Devel Generate module create sample products?

I have tried using it, but it generates some data which is not related to this, some random images, and data that is not in English.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because Questions explicitly asking to recommend, find or compare a module, theme, distribution, or other off-site resource are off-topic for Drupal Answers. Research and testing needs to be done before asking a question. Please describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

Comment: I google drupal devel generate commerce. Guess, what's the first hit?

Answer (score 2):

You can use [Devel Generate Commerce](https://www.drupal.org/project/devel_generate_commerce/) to generate Commerce Products.

Basic example: `drush devel-generate:commerce`

Advanced example: `drush devel-generate:commerce --products_num=10 --kill`